# Difference in component re-render

Tags: reactjs

Is it possible to stop component re-rendering when using Context API ?

Comment: React-redux is built on the context API if I'm not mistaken, so I'm not sure how valuable an answer would be explaining the rendering difference between the two. You also can't ***absolutely*** keep React from rerendering any component, though there are several ways to hint to React that a component shouldn't be rerendered, i.e. the `memo` HOC, and you can memoize props that are passed to children to help keep them from rerendering unnecessarily.

Answer (score 1):

React-redux will rerender your component every time the selected value changes.

So as long as `useSelector(state => state.foo.bar)` does not return a different object reference, your component will not rerender.

Context will always rerender your component anything in the context value changes, even if you are not using it in that component. Currently, there is no way around that even though the React team is considering a [`useContextSelector`](https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/20646) hook.

Generally: if any parent component rerenders, all their children and grandchildren will rerender until you manually stop it by wrapping a component in `React.memo`.

You might want to read [Blogged Answers: React, Redux, and Context Behavior](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2020/01/blogged-answers-react-redux-and-context-behavior/)

Comment: Thanks. I assume you meant........ "returns" a different object reference, your component will rerender......

Comment: I meant "does not return a different object reference, your component will not rerender." - was missing the second "not". Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: Thanks...and just one last thing...i could not locate anything about useStateSelector in the react active RFC list

Comment: Sorry, it's `useContextSelector`. Here is the PR: https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/20646

Answer (score 0):

https://redux.js.org/faq/react-redux -- You can check this link out to see how redux re-renders the components. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OvM4hIxrqAw -- Watch this youtube video to see the component rendering when using Context API vs Redux.

It is possible to stop the re-rendering of any component by using the useCallBack() hook and adding certain dependencies to the hook which will handle the re-render of the component wrapped inside this hook. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback -- Go through this page to understand the usage of useCallBack() hook.